# How to determine a source class of touch in after_touch callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to get a source class inside `after_touch` callback?
My situation is that I must not process `after_touch` callback if its source class is `BoardItemPosition`, but for remaining 8 classes that also use `belongs_to :item, touch: true` relationship I must process callback as usual.

I can not simply delete `touch: true` from `BoardItemPosition` class because this `touch` is also used by Audited gem to watch and store object versions.

```
class BoardItemPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, touch: true
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, touch: true
end

# ... 8 more classes that belongs to Item

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_touch :rtn_item_updated


  def rtn_item_updated
    return if self.touch_class == BoardItemPosition # <--- How to check a class?

    # unrelated method logic below...      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking may not be possible.  As shown in [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-touch), The only parameter `touch` callback accepts is the entity itself, you will have to use below form of callback implementation

```
after_touch do |record|
    puts "#{record.class}"
end
#=> Item
```